# How to pass boolean value from UserForm to Sub?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to close a UserForm if a person clicks the red x in the upper right hand corner.  Here is my code so far.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If target.Column = 10 Then
UserForm2.Show

etc...
```

Now, the Form opens and I run this code...

```
Public Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        If Not ExitAsk = vbYes Then Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Function ExitAsk() As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim Smsg As String
    Smsg = "Are you really want to exit? Click Yes to terminate or No to Continue."
    ExitAsk = MsgBox(Smsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Exit!")
End Function
```

Then, focus goes back to the Sub, and the code continues to run through everything, which causes some problems for me.  I want to click the red x and close the UserForm and exit the Sub.  It seem like the Sub and UserForm don't communicate, even though both are declared a Public.  I must be missing something simple, but I'm not sure what.  Any ideas, anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: VBA code is running one command at a time, top to bottom, row by row. There are some rare cases where you issue asynchronous commands. But most of the time VBA is linear. When you tell VBA to `Show` a form then the `Sub` is put on hold and waiting for the form to complete. Once the form is no longer shown the rest of the `Sub` is running. That's not a bug. That's a feature. If you don't want anything to happen after the form closes then `Form2.Show` should be the last command in that sub. If you want something to happen when the form closes then you can call a new sub upon closure of the form.

Comment: Well, that makes perfect sense.  However, it still doesn't work.  I added this:  

    If ExitAsk <> 6 Then
        Call CodeContinue
    End If

The message I get says 'Sub or Function Not Defined'.  The functions and subs are all 'Public'.

Comment: The sub `CodeContinue` will have to be on a module. If that sub is on the form or on a sheet then you cannot call it like this (even if it is public). Yet, that's another question. A question of scope and has nothing to do with the original post: linear continuity of VBA programs.

Comment: @Ralph that's all mostly correct, except OP's form isn't modal, so `UserForm2.Show` displays the form, and then execution resumes in `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` immediately, before the form is closed and after its `Initialize` [and possibly `Activate`] handler executes.

Comment: `UserForm_QueryClose` handler has no business being `Public`. The VBE makes all event handlers `Private` when you add them from the provided drop-downs - leave them `Private`. There is no reason whatsoever for any code anywhere to call any even handler explicitly, and no reason whatsoever to expose them to callers.

Comment: @Mat'sMug IN the above post the UserForm is shown using `.Show` only without any parameters. Hence, the form is shown [with the default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251540.aspx) being modal. What makes you say that the form is not modal? Also, please elaborate why you say "mostly" correct. Apparently, I got something wrong in my comment and I'd like to learn what that is (in order to get it right the next time). If you feel that this is getting too long for a comment then just email me (the address is in my profile).

Comment: @Ralph huh, TIL - I always explicitly specify `vbModal`, assuming the default is modeless. Your comment is entirely correct then, and I learned something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `UserForm` you can define your own `public` Get-property e.g. `CloseModeInfo` which will return value of private member which can be set in `UserForm_QueryClose`. Value of this public property can be then tested later. According to value in this property the calling code will decide what to do. HTH

> UserForm

```
Private m_closeModeInfo As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    m_closeModeInfo = CloseMode
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        If Not ExitAsk = vbYes Then Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ExitAsk() As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim Smsg As String
    Smsg = "Are you really want to exit? Click Yes to terminate or No to Continue."
    ExitAsk = MsgBox(Smsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Exit!")
End Function

Public Property Get CloseModeInfo() As Integer
    CloseModeInfo = m_closeModeInfo
End Property
```

> Worksheet Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If target.Column = 10 Then
        Dim frm As UserForm2
        Set frm = New UserForm2
        UserForm2.Show

        If frm.CloseModeInfo = vbFormControlMenu Then
            Unload frm
            '  I want to click the red x and close the UserForm and exit the Sub:   
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

> *It seem like the Sub and UserForm don't communicate, even though both are declared a Public*

Accessibility has nothing to do with whether a procedure *communicates* with a form. A form is an object, not very different from a `Range` or a `Collection` - except it has a *designer* and a *default instance*: it won't "communicate" with your procedure without you telling it how to do that.

First, stop using the default instance and treat the form as you would any other object: `New` it up!

```
With New UserForm2 'object instance starts existing here...
    .Show 'vbModal is implicit
End With '...and dies here
```

Now if you want the calling code to know *how* the form was closed, you need to expose *something* that the calling code can access to know that.

That's best done with a *property*. You could also expose a public field, but then the calling code would be able to tamper with it *and you don't want that* - that's what *encapsulation* does:

```
Private isCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = isCancelled
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        isCancelled = True
    End If
    Cancel = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Notice `Cancel = True` and `Me.Hide`: without cancelling the close, *the object gets destroyed immediately* and you lose its state. So you want to `Hide` the form instead of unloading/destroying it.

Only the form's code-behind can access `isCancelled`, but the calling code can read the `Cancelled` property (but not write to it).

```
With New UserForm2 'object instance starts existing here...
    .Show vbModal 'execution in this procedure will resume after form is closed
    If .Cancelled Then
        'form was X'd out
    End If
End With '...and dies here
```

So... not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly, but you'll want something along these lines.